# Please vet analysis for wrong way of computing choices for three-of-a-kind.

Tags: combinatorics, poker

It is given on page #21 of U.G. book : Combinatorics - A guided Tour, by David Mazur, [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=yI4Jx5Obr08C&pg=PA21&dq=Poker+hands+From+a+standard+52-card+deck,+how+many+different+five-card+hands+are+possible?+How+likely+is+it+that+you+will+be+dealt+three-of-a-kind&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-jN7k08zeAhWbbisKHc-DAaQQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=Poker%20hands%20From%20a%20standard%2052-card%20deck%2C%20how%20many%20different%20five-card%20hands%20are%20possible%3F%20How%20likely%20is%20it%20that%20you%20will%20be%20dealt%20three-of-a-kind&f=false) an example detailing chances of getting three-of-a-kind in 5 card hands.

The problem statement is : 
From a standard 52-card deck, how many different five-card hands are possible? How likely is it that you will be dealt three-of-a-kind?

Solution approach for the second part is:

Encode each hand as a 5-list : A B C D E; where :

1. A is the denomination of the three-of-a-kind
   $\implies$ 13 ways to choose
2. B is the 3-set of suits for the three-of-a-kind
   $\implies$ $\binom{4}{3}$
3. C is a 2-set of denominations for the other two cards
   $\implies$ $\binom{12}{2}$
4. D is the suit of the smaller denomination in C
   $\implies$ $4$ ways to choose D
5. E is the suit of the larger denomination in C
   $\implies$ $4$ ways to choose E

The chances are given by the product rule.

---

My doubt is in question #24 following that. It asks to find wrong with the below alternate approach:

There are $52$ ways to select the first card that is a part of the three-of-a-kind. Then there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick the other two cards to make up the three-of-a-kind. Finally, there are $\binom{48}{2}$ ways to pick the other two cards (any cards except those of the denomination of the three-of-a-kind). By the product principle there are $52\cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot \binom{48}{2}$.

My answer needs vetting, and is stated below in two parts. The first part concerns the first two steps:

(i) To have $52$ ways for the first card seems fine, & so is the next step to have $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to pick the other two cards. 
But the issue is that the product of first steps (by the first approach) leads to: $13\cdot \binom{4}{3} = 13\cdot 4 = 52$, while the second approach's first two steps lead to : $52\cdot \binom{3}{2} = 52\cdot 3=156$.

<del>In order to explain the multiplication factor of $3$, consider a smaller example of smaller number of denominations (let, $3$) & the same number of (i.e., $4$) suits; as it is the # of suits that matter in terms of picking three-of-a-kind.</del>
<del>$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  &A&B&C&D\\
  1&1A&1B&1C&1D\\
  2&2A&2B&2C&2D\\
  3&3A&3B&3C&3D\\
\end{array}
\right] $$</del>

<del>The duplication of choices, by factor of $\binom{3}{2}=3$, is shown below for the above small case, by considering only the first denomination (i.e. $1$), with 1A1B1C, 1A1B1D, 1A1C1D, 1B1C1D occuring $3$ times each.

I have shown only $4$ cases for the first row (i.e, denomination = $1$), but it can be easily shown that there are a total of $12(=4*3)\cdot 3= 36$ cases, of which only $12$ are original, explaining the overcount's multiplier factor of $\binom{3}{2}=3$.</del>

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  1A&1A1B1C&1A1B1D&1A1C1D\\
  1B&1B1C1A&1B1A1D&1B1C1D\\
  1C&1C1A1B&1C1A1D&1C1B1D\\
  1D&1D1A1B&1D1A1C&1D1B1C\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

---

(ii) Next comes the difference between the first approach's last 3 steps, & the second approach taking $\binom{48}{2}$. 
The first approach leads to: $(\binom{12}{2}=66) \cdot (\binom{4}{1}=4) (\binom{4}{1}=4) = 66*16 = 1056$, 
while the second approach leads to: $\binom{48}{2}=24*47= 1128$.

*Second part analysis:*  The definition of three-of-a-kind considers the denomination of the rest two cards to be different, irrespective of their suits. 
If take $\binom{48}{2}$, then also consider the cases where the third card is of the same denomination as second. This leads to an extra number of cases, that need be subtracted. 
 
I am stating here subtraction, as the number of chances for second case are found by application of sum rule.

To show how it works, by considering the original example; have extra $1128-1056 = 72$ cases.
Only $12$ denominations are available for the 4th & 5th cards, but the two cards need have different denominations. So, either can be of higher denomination than the other.

Assuming, that denomination $1$ is taken up by the three-of-a-kind; then $12$ denominations are left. In each denomination there are still $3$ more suits (for the over-calculation to occur) leading to $12*3=36$ cases, which by ordering should lead to $36*2=72$ cases.

<del>a) Fourth card denomination = $2$, fifth card denomination choices are = $3, 4, \cdots, 13$, a total of $12$ choices.

 b) Similarly, the chances based on other denominations of fourth card are : $11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1$.

This sums up to : $12 \cdot 6 = 72$ cases.</del>

Comment: Too long; didn't read. But I don't like step 2 in the book solution. Where does the 6 in $6\choose3$ come from?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for error. Edited the OP.

Comment: 52 is wrong as there are only 13 ranks. Combin(48;2) is wrong as it could include pairs.

Comment: @paparazzo I hope that the first error introduces a multiplicative factor of $3$, while the second error introduces an additive factor of $72$; as shown above.

Comment: @jiten You hope for error?

Comment: @paparazzo Yes, in my analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, we can cut down the multiple counting by first converting the problem to a problem that consider order to matter and then remove it.

$$52 \cdot \binom32 \cdot \frac{2!}{3!}=52.$$

For the second part, to reduce those that are from the same denomination:

$$12 \cdot \binom43=72$$

Comment: Thanks, but request elaboration of the ratio  $\frac{2!}{3!}$, as seemingly it is just reverse of $3C2$.

Comment: How would you answer the question, what are the number of possibility to pick $3$ cards out of $52$ such that $3$ of them share the same denomination where order matters? After you answer that, divide it by $3!$.

Comment: I feel that your last comment has an error in the last word, i.e. should end with $3$.

Comment: for having $3$ cards where order matters is $52 \times 3 \times 2$ right? to remove the order factor, divide by $3!$.

Comment: If you want to remove just the order factor of $3!$, then why multiply by $2!$ also.

Comment: There are $3$ slots, what are the number of possibility to arrange  $3$ cards out of $52$ such that they share the same denomination where order matters?

Comment: There are $4$ cards of a given denomination. To take $52$ cards is confusing. Only option is to first take one card, then take from the rest of cards, the other $2$ cards. This works as consider only a single denomination's $3$ cards. This leads to $52 \cdot \binom32 $. Further taking arrangements of these two cards, multiply by $2!$. Now, the same can occur with any card out of the three being the first one; so multiply by $3$ to get $52 \cdot \binom32 \cdot 2 \cdot 3!$. I feel that the overcount factor of $3$ cannot be justified by taking arrangements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85728/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: I wish could get you on chat now. Sorry, was not there when you visied chatroom at 7.08 IST. Have started lappy now only.

Comment: My work is over. If you wish can join chat room.

Comment: Wished that you looked at my last response in chatroom.